# find the ratio a:b, for minimum chord length

Tags: analytic-geometry

**P(a, b)** is a point in the first quadrant. Circles are drawn through P touching the coordinate axes, such that the length of common chord of these circles is **maximum**, find the ratio a : b

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  Your will have more chances to get help if you show what you have done, where you have stuck, etc.

Comment: This question makes no sense.  There are two unique circles passing through a point P and tangent to the axes, and the length of their common chord has no upper bound over all possible P.

Comment: someone actually beautifully answered my question on socratic.org, and the final answer comes out to be 3±2√2, just in case anyone wants to match his answer! also, the question DOES make a lot of sense (it is from a standard recruitment exam afterall). greenturtle's inability to comprehend the depth of the question doesn't make it nonsensical.